# How to check if values in one dataframe column are contained in another entire column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

In my project I need to check if some value exists in entire dataframe column. Example dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([['abc', 'a'], ['def', 'x'], ['aef', 'f']])
df.columns=['a', 'b']
>>>df
     a  b
0  abc  a
1  def  x
2  aef  f
```

This static code works well:

```
df['a'].str.contains('f').any()
True
```

What I need is to iterate it over rows and check if each value in "b" column is contained in entire "a" column. I did not find a way how to do it. This is what I expected should work, but it returns an error:

```
df['c']=df.apply(lambda row:df['a'].str.contains(row['b']).any())

...
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 88, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 128, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: ('b', 'occurred at index a')
```

Any idea?

**Update:**
As I see, my df is not a good example. Here is better one (including expected result):

```
     a  b      c
0  abc  a   True
1  def  b   True
2  aef  x  False
```

Comment: Why is second `True` ?

Comment: @jezrael: I am checking if each value is anywhere in entire column 'a' (here 'b' vlue is in df['a'][0])

Comment: @Chris: yes `b` can be any value

Comment: @TomasKujal - Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @TomasKujal How about `cd` in col `b`; would it be `True` or `False`?

Comment: @Chris: I need to verify, if string in b column is a substring of any value in a column. Examples of "`True` result": `a`, `ef`, `aef`; examples of "`False` result": `x`, `cba`, `fe`

Comment: @jezrael: real example: `df=pd.DataFrame([['#123 - some text', '', False], ['#124 - some text', '123', True], ['#125 - some text', '', False], ['#126 - some text', '126', True], ['#127 - some text', '123', True], ['#128 - some text', '129', False]), df.columns=['Text', 'ID', 'Expected result']`

Comment: @TomasKujal - Check answer, working nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for test:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([['#123 - some text', '', False], 
                 ['#124 - some text', '123', True], 
                 ['#125 - some text', '', False], 
                 ['#126 - some text', '126', True], 
                 ['#127 - some text', '123', True], 
                 ['#128 - some text', '129', False]],columns=['Text', 'ID', 'Expected result'])


s = df['Text'].str.extractall("(" + '|'.join(set(df['ID'])) + ")")[0].dropna()
df['new'] = df['ID'].isin(s)
print (df)
               Text   ID  Expected result    new
0  #123 - some text                 False  False
1  #124 - some text  123             True   True
2  #125 - some text                 False  False
3  #126 - some text  126             True   True
4  #127 - some text  123             True   True
5  #128 - some text  129            False  False
```

**Details**:

First create pattern of all unique values by sets with `|` for regex `OR`:

```
print ("(" + '|'.join(set(df['ID'])) + ")")
(|123|129|126)
```

Then extract all matched values from `Text`, remove missing values by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and last test membership by `isin`:

```
print (df['Text'].str.extractall("(" + '|'.join(set(df['ID'])) + ")")[0].dropna())
   match
0  2        123
3  2        126
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the magic after **extractall**, but it really works :-) Thanks